# Get hash (number range) from string/ID

Tags: c#

I have a list of items with a given `ID`. This ID is currently an int but I could cast it to a string if necessary.

Example ID: **495197527**

In my application I want to assign a different color (from a pool of 8 colors) to each item.
This color (saved as a number) should be the same all the time and derived from the ID.

If I would hash the ID - for example with MD5 - it would result in a 32-length string which is always the same for an item.

I need exactly the same just with the result within the range from **0-7**. In other words, a random number for an item which shouldn't change, even if I create it for the item again.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: `var myhash = id & 7` :) .....

Comment: L.B your answer is great thanks. Totally forgot that bitwise operations exist :D Would you be so kind and post this as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Parts of a MD5 hash should be uniformly distributed, perhaps you should check this in your situation ( so that you get all the colors in your range). You can always try different bits, shift them etc.